# "Operation already completed" error when using Progress Bar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I currently have the following:

**View Model**

```
MovieProcessor movieProcessor = new MovieProcessor(SelectedPath, this);

BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += movieProcessor.processMovie_DoWork;
worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

progressBar.Show();
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**worker_ProgressChanged**

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

In my `MovieProcessor` class, I have the method `processMovie_DoWork`.

```
public async void processMovie_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < totalFilesToProcess; ++x)
    {
         // Do stuff like calling API

         (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(x);

    }
}
```

The **second time** `ReportProgress(x)` is called, I get the error:

`This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.`

`CurrentProgress` is bound to my `XAML`

```
<ProgressBar  Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding MaxValueProgressBar}"  Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Would anyone have any idea as to what might be happening here?

Comment: Try removing `async` from your method

Comment: I had that same error message but a different cause, it was caused by a call to report progress after the background worker had completed. The root cause for me was a callback coming from an external library after my background worker was done

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment from dkozl:

It is possible that the `async` is causing the problem. There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause an issue, but of course the code example you posted is far from complete.

If you have an `await` statement in your `processMovie_DoWork()` method (which is the usual reason one makes a method `async`), then the method will execute only as far as the point of the first `await` statement, and then it will exit.

As far as the `BackgroundWorker` class is considered, this marks the end of the work. It has no way to know that some continuation would be called. Thus, when you call the `ReportProgress()` method, the operation has in fact completed, making the call to `ReportProgress()` illegal.

You have a couple of options here:

1. Get rid of the `await` statements and perform those operations synchronously. Preferably by calling the synchronous version of the API.
2. Get rid of the `BackgroundWorker` and just call your `processMovie_DoWork()` method directly (albeit likely renamed to something else). In this case, instead of calling the `ReportProgress()` method, you'd just update the `CurrentProgress` property directly.

IMHO, the second option is much preferable. You can simply `await` your `processMovie_DoWork()` method, and avoid all the hassle of dealing with `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this problem trying to poll status from a Web API using Background Worker.
I resolved this by removing `async` and changing the `await` operator to `Task.Wait()` and it worked perfectly.

Here is my Code in place of "`// Do stuff like calling API`" :

```
var task = JobManager.GetJobStatus(id);
task.Wait();
var status = task.Result;
```

I hope this helps somebody else. I am sure you got over this issue.